# replace increment number in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

i have .sql file dump that have increment id 1 - 1001
I want to replace the number to be `null`.

This is some .sql content :

```
INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES(2, 'test');
INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES(3, 'BATUK DARAH');
INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES(4, 'SESAK NAFAS');
INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES(5, 'mual dan muntah');
INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES(6, 'muntah darah');
INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES(7, 'batuk rejan');
....
INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES(1001, 'Lorem ipsum');
```

How to replace automatically using notepad++ ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your requirements are not completely clear, but with this answer you should be able to handle your task.

Search for e.g.

```
VALUES\(\d+
```

and replace with

```
VALUES\(
```

results in

> INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES(, 'test');

make sure to check the search mode "Regular Expression".

`\d+` is matching a sequence of at least one digits.

If you want to also remove the comma, just add it and the following whitespace to the search term `VALUES\(\d+,\s*`.

would result in

> INSERT INTO `complaint` (`Id`, `complaint_name`) VALUES('SESAK NAFAS');

Answer (score 0):

I am aware that you wanted to replace with null here, but if you ever need to replace with a new incremental value, you could use the column editor (Alt-C) instead of search and replace.

First you select the column that you want to have replaced (holding ALT and SHIFT while selecting vertical text), and then press Alt-C  to open the column editor, where you can select "number to insert" and type a starting number and increment.

It is more work than search-and-replace, but still it is extremely helpful in such situations.